# How to communicate with multiple servers using the single class defined in python and run it parallel

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python class that communicates with a server. That python class has many functions, i was using few functions. But i want to access multiple servers data at same time using the python class i have.
Am trying something like this, but it'll run one after the other. And i wanted to get the data at same time.

```
import threading
from server_class import server

class runMonitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        self.func()

def monitorSB(ipAddr):
    sb = server(ipAddr)
    sb.readInfo()
    print ('\nReading Registers...\n')
    sb.read_rx()
    sb.read_tx()
    i = 0
    while(1):
        if i == 0:
            print 'Monitoring Registers...'
            i = 1
        sb.monitor_tx()
        sb.monitor_rx()


t = runMonitor(monitorSB('192.168.10.78'))
q = runMonitor(monitorSB('192.168.10.101'))

t.start()
q.start()

print ('\nTest Done...\n')
```

In the above code, i wanted to access both servers at same time. Help me how to run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

The thing is by saying `monitorSB('192.168.10.78')` it will execute it before passing it to your thread. Try this:

```
import threading
from server_class import server

class runMonitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func, param):
        self.func = func
        self.param = param

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        self.func(self.param)

def monitorSB(ipAddr):
    sb = server(ipAddr)
    sb.readInfo()
    print ('\nReading Registers...\n')
    sb.read_rx()
    sb.read_tx()
    i = 0
    while(1):
        if i == 0:
            print 'Monitoring Registers...'
            i = 1
        sb.monitor_tx()
        sb.monitor_rx()


t = runMonitor(monitorSB, '192.168.10.78')
q = runMonitor(monitorSB, '192.168.10.101')

t.start()
q.start()

print ('\nTest Done...\n')
```